# Is it possible to find the project boards an issue is associated with using the Github API?

Tags: github, github-api

I'm developing a Github webhook that gets notifications on issue updates.

These issues are associated to one of more [Github Project Boards](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/about-project-boards)

The body payload shows this information related to the updated issue:

[image]

Nothing about issue association with project boards. Is there a way to get this information?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GraphQL API](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql) to get that information using `projectCards` under the Issue object :

```graphql
{
  repository(name: "caipy-dashboard", owner: "bertrandmartel") {
    issue(number: 26) {
      title
      projectCards {
        nodes {
          createdAt
          column {
            name
          }
          project {
            name
            body
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output :

```json
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "issue": {
        "title": "fix dead path in startover",
        "projectCards": {
          "nodes": [
            {
              "createdAt": "2017-08-28T05:47:49Z",
              "column": {
                "name": "Done"
              },
              "project": {
                "name": "Startover",
                "body": "Show epg / caipy events + startover modes"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20repository%28name%3A%20%22caipy-dashboard%22%2C%20owner%3A%20%22bertrandmartel%22%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20issue%28number%3A%2026%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20title%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20projectCards%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nodes%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20createdAt%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20column%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20project%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20body%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)